# Running Python script calling packages in terminal

Tags: python, terminal, package

I have a Pycharm project with the following tree:

```
-- Sources
   |--__init__.py
   |--Calculators
      |--__init__.py
      |--Filters.py
   |--Controllers
      |--__init__.py
      |--FiltersController.py
   |--Viewers
      |--__init__.py
      |--DataVisualization.py
   |--Models
      |--__init__.py
      |--Data
```

Where my Filters.py calls:

```
import Sources.Models.Data as Dt
```

My FilterController.py calls:

```
import Sources.Calculators.Filters as Fs
import Sources.Models.Data as Dt
```

And so on.

First, my __init__.py is actually my **main**. Its imports look like this:

```
import Calculators.Filters as Fs
import Controllers.FiltersController as Fc
import Models.Data as Dt
import Viewers.DataVisualization as Dv
```

I don't think that my __init__.py working as my **main** is correct, but it was the way I could do __Filters.py__ and __FilterController.py__ find **Sources**. When I run this with Pycharm it works great. However, when I run __init__.py in terminal, I got a bunch of errors like this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
    import Calculators.Filters as Fs
  File "/Users/paulaceccon/PycharmProjects/UncertaintyQuantificationOfFilters/Sources/Calculators/Filters.py", line 6, in <module>
    import Sources.Models.Data as Dt
ImportError: No module named Sources.Models.Data
```

I am wondering how I could do this properly, in order to have the correct Python way to use packages and to be able to run it in terminal without Pycharm.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You hava an typo. In the folders, you named it as "Model". But when importing, you named it as "Models". In addition, you need to add the directory to Python's searching paths:

```
package = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.realpath(__file__)))
sys.path.append(package)
```

You should add these lines in the outest **init**.py

Comment: The typo was just a mistake writing here. But thank you very much, it worked. (: